# Allow a user to vote only once. Django

Tags: django

What I have in my `models.py`:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # The rest of code...

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # The rest of code...

class Voter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
```

What I have in my `vote` view in `views.py`:

```
@login_required
def vote(request, poll_id):
    # Some code...
    # And here is the checking happens.
    voters = [user.id for user in Voter.objects.filter(poll__id=poll_id)]
    if request.user.id in voters:
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'poll': p,
        'error_message': "Sorry, but you have already voted."
        })
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'poll': p,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice."
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes +=1
        selected_choice.save()
        v = Voter(user=request.user, poll=p)
        v.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

But this code works a little bit strange.

I have created 5 polls for testing purposes. *And this code works only for **one** of them.*
Only in one of this polls I get the error message when I try to vote twice.
In the rest of this polls the code gives the opportunity to vote as many times as you want.

And I have no idea why. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You could simply do it yourself by adding `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` after _# And here is the checking happens._. Then look at `voters` values, perhaps they are not the ones you expected.

Comment: FYI: you can make this: `Voter.objects.filter(poll_id=poll_id, user_id=request.user.id).exists()` to check if user already voted. Regarding the question, can you please post the test code that gives unexpected result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Voter` ids won't necessarily fit your `User` ids.  This explains why you see it sometimes appear to work (when voter id and user id accidentally match up). Replace:

```
voters = [user.id for user in Voter.objects.filter(poll__id=poll_id)]
if request.user.id in voters:
```

with

```
if Voter.objects.filter(poll_id=poll_id, user_id=request.user.id).exists()
```

It is better practice to let the database backend do the checks for you.