# Restrict each user to only vote once (Polls, django, python)

Tags: python, django

I found an similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880152/allow-a-user-to-vote-only-once-django), but unlike there and unlike in django official tutorial , I don't have a separate Choice class. How can I restrict every user to vote just one? What should I change in my code?

my models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Law(models.Model):
    #some code here
    yes_votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Voter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    law = models.ForeignKey(Law)
```

my views.py:

```
class LawDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Law
    template_name = 'law_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any petitions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Law.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())


class LawResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Law
    template_name = 'law_results.html'






def law_yes_vote(request, law_id):
    if Voter.objects.filter(law_id=law_id, user_id=request.user.id).exists():

        return render(request, 'law_detail.html', {
        'law': p,
        'error_message': "Sorry, but you have already voted."
        })

    else:
        p = get_object_or_404(Law, pk=law_id)
        p.yes_votes += 1
        p.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('laws:law_results', args=(p.id,)))



def law_no_vote(request, law_id):
    if Voter.objects.filter(law_id=law_id, user_id=request.user.id).exists():

        return render(request, 'law_detail.html', {
        'law': p,
        'error_message': "Sorry, but you have already voted."
        })

    else:
        p = get_object_or_404(Law, pk=law_id)
        p.no_votes += 1
        p.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('laws:law_results', args=(p.id,)))
```

my law_detail.html:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
{% if error_message %}
<h1 >{{ error_message }}</h1>  

{% else %}

<div class="row" id="row-voting">
<form action="{% url 'laws:law_yes_vote' law.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

<button class="btn btn-success" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" > 
<label >YES</label>
</form>
<form action="{% url 'laws:law_no_vote' law.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

<button class="btn btn-danger" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" > 
<label >NO</label>
</form>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% else %}

<h1>Please, register</h1>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Kind of depends how important it is. If it's a toy example, adding a `has_voted` boolean to the `Voter` class and setting it in your view after their vote is recorded is likely sufficient. If this is "for real", you could have all kinds of spoofing attacks to consider and the question is likely too broad.

Comment: good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have forgotten to create the `voter` instance after the user has voted.

```
def law_yes_vote(request, law_id):
    if Voter.objects.filter(law_id=law_id, user_id=request.user.id).exists():

        return render(request, 'law_detail.html', {
            'law': p,
            'error_message': "Sorry, but you have already voted."
        })

    else:
        p = get_object_or_404(Law, pk=law_id)
        p.yes_votes += 1
        p.save()
        Voter.objects.create(law_id=law_id, user_id=request.user.id)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('laws:law_results', args=(p.id,)))
```

You'll need to update `law_no_vote` in the same way.